# Porque estoy obteniendo undefined de mi variable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy obteniendo undefined de una variable llamada $detailData la cual se la paso a la vista en un metodo.

```php
public function find($id)
{
    $detailData = Product::find($id);
    
    return view('backend.products.view', $detailData);
}
```

Esta es mi ruta que accede al metodo:

```php
Route::get('/find/{id}', 'Backend\ProductController@find')->name('products.find');
```

Y esta es mi tabla en la vista:

```xml
<tbody>
  <tr>                                  
    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->marca->brandName }}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->modelo->modelName}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->coin}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->cost}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->fob}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->costUSD}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->costUSDB}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->costNacionalizacion}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->costARS}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->list_price}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->ML_price}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->distributor_price}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->limit_price}}</td>
    <td>{{ $detailData->description }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo mandas a llamar a esta ruta? ¿Donde es donde te marca el error? Los valores undefined suelen ser de javascript, un dato undefined de php sería null

Answer (score 1):

El segundo argumento del [helper `view`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views) es un array el cual te ayudará a pasar datos a la vista.

Entonces tu código tendría que ir así (*asignando el posible objeto recuperado a la variable `details`*):

```
return view('backend.products.view', ["details" => $detailData]);
```

Incluso si no quieres usar dicha sintaxis puedes emplear el [metodo `compact`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.compact.php) de PHP de este modo:

```
return view('backend.products.view', compact('detailData'));
```

Comment: Ya lo habia intentado asi y sigue devolviendome undefined

Comment: Con ambas opciones te devuelve undefined?

Comment: asi es en ambos casos me devuelve undefined

Comment: Se me ocurre que limpies la caché de las vistas que ya se han compilado y pruebes de nuevo con ambas opciones

Comment: La primera opción no va a funcionar si la variable que accede en la vista es `$detailData` y no `$details`. Para la segunda opción, claro quizás tenga que limpiar el caché de vistas con `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @IGP respecto a lo que mencionas, eso ya depende del OP yo solo coloqué como ejemplo como mandar datos a la vista que previamente pudiera tener en una variable asignados, incluso se puede colocar la query de forma directa quitando a $detailData